# Java get JSON data from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java

I want to get Json key values from HttpServletRequest.

My Java code is given below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@WebServlet("/Service")
public class Service extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                jb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
            String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Post JSON

```
{
    "email": "test@xyz.com",
    "fname": "test01"
}
```

I am getting below JSON output using `JSONObject jsonObject = HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());`

```
{"\"test@xyz.com\",\t\"fname\"":"\"test01\"}","Request-URI":"email","Method":"{","HTTP-Version":":"}
```

I am not getting any value using `String email = jsonObject.getString("email");`

I am using Eclipse Mars 1 using JAVA.

Answer (score -1):

How are you passing your json in?

If you are passing it in as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then the above won't work - you should use something like

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("mydata"));
```

where `mydata` is the name of the HTML form field.

If you use `Content-Type: application/json`, the code you provided should work. Can you confirm that?

It's worth anyway to output the contents of `jb.toString()` in the servlet, so you can see what came into it before trying to parse it as JSON if it's invalid already.

If you can use curl, test your code with:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email": "test@xyz.com","fname": "test01"}'
```

or the code such as in the last reference below.

References:

- [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-json-post-data)
- [READ JSON String in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet)
- [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)
- [Sending JSON over HTTP POST with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684699/sending-json-over-http-post-with-java)